# Scala pattern matching aggregate multiple matches

Tags: scala

If I have a case class

```
case class Test(a: Option[Boolean], b: Option[Boolean], c: Option[Boolean], d: Option[Boolean])
```

and I have to do find out a `Boolean` result that all of the parameters of class `Test` amount to. For example:

```
Test(None, None, Some(true), Some(false))
```

should result in `false` and

```
Test(Some(true), None, Some(true), None)
```

would result in `true`

I was thinking to use pattern matching, however I would have to match every possible scenario and that's a lot, plus if adding more parameters the code grows exponentially.

But could I do something like

```
Test(Some(true), None, Some(true), None) match {
    case (_, _, _, Some(b)) => b
    case (_, _, Some(b), _) => b
    case (_, Some(b), _, _) => b
    case (Some(b), _, _, _) => b
}
```

and aggregate all the `b`'s into a single `Boolean` result?

Comment: Do you want find `conjuction` between all non-None values?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Yes, I guess you could call it that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the conjunction of all defined arguments, consider this,

```
case class Test(a: Option[Boolean], 
                b: Option[Boolean], 
                c: Option[Boolean], 
                d: Option[Boolean]) {

  def and() = this.productIterator
                  .collect { case Some(b: Boolean) => b }.reduce(_&&_)
}
```

A case classes extend `trait Product` which equip the instances with methods for processing the arguments.

Thus,

```
Test(None, None, Some(true), Some(false)).and()
res: false

Test(Some(true), None, Some(true), None).and()
res: true
```

Here we iterate over all values of type `Any` as delivered by `productIterator`,  and collect those that are defined and convertible to `Boolean`; the call to `reduce` will deliver the conjunction of all collected `Boolean`.

**Update**

A well-defined version,

```
case class Test(a: Option[Boolean], 
                b: Option[Boolean], 
                c: Option[Boolean], 
                d: Option[Boolean]) {

  def and() = {
    val b = this.productIterator.collect { case Some(b: Boolean) => b }
    if (b.isEmpty) false else b.reduce(_&&_)
  }
}
```

Comment: but 'Test(None, None, None, None).and()' yields 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft'

Comment: @j-keck thanks for the insight, please note update... it should be now well defined (or better-defined :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just care for the combined results just use a **List** **flatten** it and **forall**.

```
 scala> List(Some(true), None, Some(false), Some(true)).flatten.forall(identity)
 res2: Boolean = false
```

As it has not been defined what should happen if there are only **None**s you have to describe the case by checking it explicitly and what you want to happen in that case.

Comment: but this 'List(None, None).flatten.forall(_ == true)' yields also 'true'

Comment: This case was not defined at all so what should be the value when all results are None ? Is it then true by default or false by default ?

Comment: The code given in the question would throw an exception if there are only None for example.